# How to backup progresses in Candy Crush Soda for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, candy-crush-soda

When I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1 I noticed the presence of the game "Candy Crush Soda Saga" in the start menù (I don't know if it was already there in Win8.1 because I never used the metro start screen).

I started playing this game and beated quite some levels, now that I have to reinstall windows I would like to back-up my progresses, where are they?

*I should point out that I never registered myself with the game's company, nor associated the game with my facebook profile. When I started the game I was logged in Windows with my Microsoft account, then some times later I logged out from the Microsoft account and started using Windows with my local account, so the progresses should reside on my PC only.*

I know that the app is in this folder "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\king.com.CandyCrushSodaSaga_1.65.800.0_x86__kgqvnymyfvs32"  but are the savegames there too?

P.S. I cannot log in and create a profile now, because all Windows 10 apps stopped working (even the start menu and edge), that's one of the reasons why I'm reinstalling Windows.